# Arrangements and permutation

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many arrangements of $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H$ are there such that $A$

and B are between C and D ?

Attempt : I am trying to solve this problem using simple counting process like first place can be occupy by 6 persons second occupied by 6 and so forth I tried to manipulate remaining one. But it seems confusing and I am missing some terms is what I feel . Please help me to solve this with effective approach.

Comment: **Hint:** Pick the positions for $A,B,C,D$ simultaneously.  Once you know where those four troublesome letters are... what more do you need to do to make sure that $A$ and $B$ are between $C$ and $D$?  What more do you need to do for the remaining letters and remaining positions?

Comment: Hint: 1)  Pick $4$ spots from $8$ for $A,B,C,D$. 2) Assign $C,D$ to the outer $2$ spots you chose. 3) Assign $A,B$ to the inner spots. 4) Assign the other letters to the remaining spots. Then multiply the numbers of choices in the $4$ steps.

Comment: [direct counting](https://tio.run/##VYzLDoIwEEX3fMXsmG6IyMaFaaL4@gfCgoQSh0fblGmiX18tGKObuzj35Ngn340udtaFQJM1joFYOTZmnBPrSDPOfsIcOuNgANKA7O2okDLSrXpgL5arj1d6OJan8@V6S1dIEX5zmVVu8twwGT3jjyuAOsCh2tb7odrEKWpodAsflK9IwDu5aDJq8k@TUVuQECIJ4QU) gives $6720$.

Comment: @JMoravitz please help I am not getting correct answer.

Comment: $\binom{8}{4}\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 4! = 6720$.  Choose the positions of the four troublesome letters.  Choose whether $C$ is first and $D$ is last or if $D$ is first and $C$ is last.  Choose whether $A$ is second and $B$ is third or if $B$ is second and $A$ is third.  Arrange the remaining letters in the remaining positions.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't have the constraint about $A,B$ being between $C,D$, then you'd have $8!=40,320$ arrangements. Now consider the positions of $A,B,C,D$ in each of those arrangements. In each arrangement, exactly one of the six pairs $AB$, $AC$, $AD$, $BC$, $BD$, and $CD$ will lie between the other two of $A,B,C,D$. So you can classify the $40,320$ arrangements into $6$ classes according to which pair lies between the others. Each of those $6$ classes has, by symmetry, the same number of elements, $40,320\,/\,6$. And your problem asks for the number of arrangements in one of the classes. So the answer is $40,320\,/\,6=6720$.